# .NET MAUI: how to examine SQLite db on Android phone for newbies

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sqlite, maui

### What the Problem?

*NOTE: in case I fail to mention it elsewhere, everything in this question is for Android.*

I have an SQLite db saved on an emulator created using Visual Studio's Android Emulator.
Using curses and duct tape I've managed to cobble together a method that allows me to examine the contents of said database, but it's broken.

### EDIT: a good way to examine an SQLite database that's on a phone/emulator for Android

I erased my long-winded question because I solved my problem.  Instead I will explain a good method of how to examine an SQLite database on an emulator/Android phone.  Note that this explanation will be step-by-step, so it'll be long-winded, too.  It's for newbies like me.

**Assumptions**
This is assuming that you have an *SQLite* database saved somewhere on either an Android phone or an Android emulator.  These directions will be emulator-specific, but it should be fine on a phone, too.

### What you'll need

**adb.exe**
Stands for "Android Debug something-or-other".  It's the command line interface for Android.  You already have it installed.  Go to your Android SDK to find it (probably here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`).

I initially put the executable into an environment variable, but it turns out it also needs the dlls and stuff in the sdk, so every time the command called for something like `adb command` I put in:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\adb.exe" command`.  If you can shorten that, do it.

**The location of your database on your device/emulator**
You can do this with a tiny bit of code.  I created a class:

```
namespace MyProject;
public class GetPathToDb
{
    public static string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
    {
        return Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);
    }
}
```

This will return a string.  This is what it returned for me (the name of the database I created was called "database"):

```
/data/user/0/com.Android.myproject/files/database.db3
```

**Admin access to Visual Studio**
Some workspaces don't give their employees admin access, and if this is the case... I'm sorry.
I normally don't run Visual Studio as admin, so when I tried it gave me a ton of hassle.  Eventually I solved it like this:
Sign out of your Windows user and sign in as admin.  Boot up Visual Studio.  Take a well-deserved break.  Turn off Visual Studio, sign out as admin, sign back in as yourself, then try to run Visual Studio as admin.  It should allow you to sign in as admin this time (provided you know the admin username/pw, of course).

**DB Browser**
Is a small program with a gui that allows you to navigate around SQLite databases (`.db3` files).  Download [here](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/). Of course, you can use the [SQLite CLI](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html), but if you don't have the time to learn it, use this.

### How to copy SQLite database from emulator/phone to local machine

Running Visual Studio as admin, make sure your emulator is running and that whatever code you used to create the SQLite database has been run (so the database is on the emulator).

Open the Android ADB Command Prompt (Tools >> Android >> Android ADB Command Prompt).

Make sure that at least the root folder of the path to your database is there (in this example the root folder is `data`, as in `data/.../database.db3`) by running this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\adb.exe" shell ls /
```

This will return a bunch of folders, and hopefully the root folder of the path to your database is among them.

As a side note, if you get the message *permission denied*, try running the command *root*, like so:
[image]

This isn't necessary, but you can navigate to the database file itself from the adb command line.  To do so, you have to open the actual ADB shell by putting in the command "shell":

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\adb.exe" shell
```

This will give you a prompt that ends with a pound:
[image]

From there, you can use the command `cd /path/to/folder`, then `ls`:
[image]

Use the command `pull` to copy the database file from the device to a spot on your local machine.  Here's the full syntax:

```
"C:/Program Files(x86)/.../adb.exe" pull path/to/db/filename.db path/to/local/folder
```

It will look sort of like this:
[image]

If the command worked, you'll see the file on your local machine!
[image]

Finally, you can open the `.db3` file using the program *DB Browser* (or whatever program you like, really).

Note that you can get any file off an emulator with this method.

Comment: It might be!  It's certainly worth a shot.  I know nothing about adb, so there will be a little bit of a learning curve there, but... what, it's just a command line interface for Android, right?  I'll let you know.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't even know it came with Android SDK!  Shows you what I know, huh?